# Remove punctuation (comma) after year

Tags: biblatex, punctuation, italic

For American Society of Genetics journal (Genetics), the bibliography format is somewhat strange.  It requires no parenthesis or comma after year field.

Beadle, G. B. et al. 2009 Title of the paper. Non-Italic-Name-of-Journal 88: 203-209

I am getting: Beadle, G. B. et al. 2009.  Title.... And the journal name is printing in *italics*.

Can someone help me with getting rid of the period after the 'year' field and removing the italicized Journal font?

Edit1: I am using biblatex with authoryear style and natbib=true.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit your question to provide a hyperlink to the bibliography style file, or at least the name of this file? Thanks.

Comment: @Mico One of the tags is biblatex, so more than the style we need the  biblatex options (including the style)

Answer (score 7):

It might depends on the  specific style used, but for standard `biblatex` `authoryear` style, one should be able to remove the punctuation after the year with

```
\renewcommand{\labelnamepunct}{\addspace}
```

and to prevent the journal title to be printed in italics, the  following should do the trick

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{#1}
```

Comment: Perfect Guido!  Both solutions work very well.  Since I am new to biblatex, its rather difficult to make the connection between identifiers such as labelnamepunct to year punctuations.  But I am glad to see that Biblatex has so many options available.  This is much better than editing .bst.

Comment: @cryptic0 That one is a very hard one indeed. The problem is that the spec to print the year in the authoryear style is inside the macro for translator, which is then inside that of author/editor+other.

Comment: Just to say that in never versions `\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nameyeardelim}{\addspace}` is the preferred (if slightly longer) solution.